# set up background from cli with feh

Tags: desktop-environments, mate, ubuntu-mate, desktop-background

I've read the manual pages from feh, and this command should work:

```bash
feh --fullscreen --no-menus --randomize --recursive --bg-fill wallpapers/
```

I can see a flicker on the screen, but my old background seems to be re-set on top of the feh background.

I am using Ubuntu Mate 22.04.

And the command I have tried both, from CLI and from start up applications, none sets the background.

I presume there is some conflict between gnome and my feh commands but there isn't any documentation that I found useful.

How could I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Open a terminal and run the following command to disable the default background handling by gnome-settings-daemon (this hides the desktop icons, you can skip that option.):

   ```bash
   gsettings set org.mate.background show-desktop-icons false
   ```
2. Run your feh command

Comment: Setting `show-desktop-icons true` or skipping that option prevents *gsettings* of setting the wallpaper.